# Javascript/GAS- How can I loop through dates in a POST request

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to post some timesheet entries for the next month into a system via API. For this I need

1. user_id
2. assignable_id
3. Dates (Format YYYY-MMM-DD)
4. Hours

First I downloaded user_id and assignable_id and stored them in an array and now am trying to use them to send a POST request to the system.

My challenge is, I am having trouble getting dates into an array and loop through each day in the array whenever the POST requests are made. Any pointers on how I can achieve this inside the POST loop?

Here is the code for POST request:

```
function demo_Code()
{
var user_dt = user_assignments()

for (var i = 0; i < user_dt.length; i++)
  {

     var data = {

      'hours': 0,
//      'date': lastRow[0][2],   // This is where I need to change and have next one month datesin an array instead of reading through the sheet
      'user_id': user_dt[i].user_id,
      'assignable_id': user_dt[i].assignable_id,
    };
    var payload = JSON.stringify(data);
    var options = {
      'method': 'POST',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'payload': data,
    };

    var url = 'https://api.10000ft.com/api/v1/users/' + data.user_id + '/time_entries?auth=' + token
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
     }

}
```

Comment: I cannot understand your current issue and your goal from `My challenge is, I am having trouble getting dates into an array and loop through each day in the array whenever the POST requests are made.` and `This is where I need to change and have next one month datesin an array instead of reading through the sheet`. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of it? If you can do, can you provide the sample values you expect? From this, I would like to try to understand your question.

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks for your response. Actually What I need is to have dates for the next one month in an array and then loop through those days. The dates stored in this array should be in the format YYYY-MM-DD. I hope this makes sense?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand what you want to do from your replying. If you can do, can you provide the sample values you expect? From this, I would like to try to understand your question.

Comment: @Tanaike, I expect dates in array e.g 2021-02-01, 2021-02-02,2021-02-03, 2021-02-04,......2021-02-30,. Thirty days dates. Then I would like to loop through all these dates. Does this make sense

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case, can I ask you about the relationship between the date strings and the value of `user_dt`? You want to use all date strings for each element? Or you want to use a date string for a element?

Comment: Hi ! Do you need to generate these dates or are them in the ```dt``` array's objects? Is your problem related to creating this array of dates?

Comment: @MateoRandwolf, Thanks for your response. I need to generate the dates. They are not part of dt'

Comment: @Tanaike There is no relationship between the dates in the value user_dt. Will need to generate this dates and store them in an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you have described in your question and comments your intention is to generate a date array containing all the days between two days.

To achieve so, you could use the simple code below that has self explanatory comments. It basically iterates over all the days between two dates by keeping a "date count" that increases the day by one after each day is added to your array. This is achieved using the functions [getDate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate) and [setDate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate).

If you want to use this array then in your `POST` for loop you can simply access each date element by its index `dateArray[2]` for example and this index can also be your iteration variable `i` (`dateArray[i]`).

```js
 // Array of dates
 var dateArray = [];
 // Starting date
 var date1= new Date(2021,1,1);
 // Ending date for the range of dates
 var date2 = new Date(2021,1,31);

// Set the current date to the starting date 
 var date = new Date(date1); 

// Iterate over all the dates from the starting
// to the end date
 while(date<=date2){
 // push the current date
   dateArray.push(date);
 // move the current date to be one day later
   date.setDate(date.getDate()+1);
 }
// log your date array
 Logger.log(dateArray);
```